# Resize an image from data entered in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

ive a form with a image , button and textbox. ive to resize the images height and width to what ever is entered in the textbox, when the button is clicked. My image just disappears when the button is clicked.

heres my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Resize Image</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function resizeimage()
    {
        var theImg = document.getElementById('image');
        theImg.height = size;
        theImg.width = size;
    }
    var size=parseInt(document.getElementById('txtbox'));   
</script>


<form name ="ResizeImage">
<img src = "cookie.jpg" id="image">
</br>
<input type=button value="Resize" onclick="resizeimage()">
</br>
<input type=text id="txtbox"

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `theImg.style.height`. I'm not sure if it'd work.

Comment: I think you should put `var size=parseInt(document.getElementById('txtbox'));` into the function, because now the size value is only initialized onload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the HTML problems (please run it through the validator), the main problem is that the part of code that reads the size of the image is outside of the function. On page load, this is what happens.

1. The function `resizeimage()` is defined
2. The var `size` is set to whatever is in the input at that point
3. The contents of the page are loaded.

At 2. the input doesn't even exist yet because 3. isn't done yet, so var `size` is set to `undefined`. It never changes after that, because the function `resizeimage()` does not try to read the size of the image again.

Also, `document.getElementById` returns an element. You will have to read what the user put into it by using it's `.value` property

Try this:

```
function resizeimage()
{
    var size=parseInt(document.getElementById('txtbox').value);   
    var theImg = document.getElementById('image');
    theImg.height = size;
    theImg.width = size;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KZH5p/

Answer (score 1):

I would cache the ids first:

```
var input = document.getElementById('txtbox');
var theImg = document.getElementById('image');

function resizeimage() {
  var size = input.value;
  theImg.height = size;
  theImg.width = size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeDogsSize() {
    var dogSize = parseInt((id_input).value);
    id_dog.width = dogSize;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container bg-light mt-3"></div>

     <!--changing dogs image-->
     <div class="container">
         <img id="id_dog" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e4/9d/75/e49d755afcd02cdbf39d374b42a10ecd.jpg"  alt="dog">
         <input id="id_input" type="text" class="form-control mt-4" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="enter img width">
         <button id="id_changeBtn" onclick="changeDogsSize()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-3 text-dark">Change</button>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```